# Nested JsonObject to String

Tags: java, json

I want to convert the value of 'points' to a string. Initially, it is an Object.

```
{
        "note": "testing",
        "Area": "India",
        "workId": "21390",
        "points": {
            "value1": [
                [
                    [1, 2],
                    [3, 4]
                ]
            ],
            "value2": 5,
            "value3": {
                "q": 1111,
                "l": 0011
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use the below code but it giving me "deserialize instance of java.lang.String"

```
if (Json_object.has("points"))
{
    String string = Json_object.getJSONObject("points").toString();
    payload.put("points",string);
    /*more code */
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: You must provide a full, minimal code. This code is not complete. You must share an example of what is your expected output.

Comment: exactly as @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero said. You should follow this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not an approach to deal with a JSON object.

- You should write POJO classes for your JSON object. Using this site (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), you can convert JSON to java classes easily.
- Then use Jackson or Gson like converter, to convert JSON object to java object. Follow the tutorial for more details, https://howtodoinjava.com/jackson/jackson-convert-object-to-from-json/
- Inside your Points class, write your own toString() method/logic.

This is a reusable and straightforward way.